# Disable a button helper after one click(MVC)

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

I have a button (custom helper) that I want to disable after a click and apply a style for it when its disabled(css and special text).

a snippet from my helper using a script for disabling :

```
    var sb = new StringBuilder();
         sb.AppendFormat("<script>$(function(){{ $('#{0}').one('click',function(){{ $(this).replaceWith"
        + "('<input type=\"submit\" id=\"'+ $(this).attr('id') + '\" value=\"' + $(this).val() + '\"class=\"btn-disabled btn "
        + "btn-full-mobile\" disabled=\"disabled\" onclick=\"return false;\" />' )}}); }});</script>", style.Id);
        sb.AppendFormat("<input type=\"submit\" id=\"{0}\" value=\"{1}\" {2}>", style.Id, style.Text, this.CalculateCssClass(style));
        TextWriter.WriteLine(sb.ToString());
```

and I want to add this style when its disabled(code from webform custom control that I want to convert to MVC)

```
protected override void Render(HtmlTextWriter writer)
{
    this.CssClass = this.CalculateCssClass();
    // if not disabled text specified just keep the value of the active button  
    const string DisabledButton = "<input type=\"submit\" id=\"{0}\" value=\"{1}\" class=\"btn-disabled btn btn--full-mobile\" disabled=\"disabled\" onclick=\"return false;\" >";
    base.Render(writer);
    writer.Write(DisabledButton, this.ClientID + "_Disabled", this.DisabledText ?? this.Text);
}
```

so where to put this in the first code?

Comment: Use `one('click', fn)` instead of `click()`.

Comment: You should probably use  `$(this).prop('disabled', true);` instead of `$(this).attr('disabled', 'disabled');` as `disabled` is a property, not an attribute.

Comment: @AlexArt. no, `one()`. See http://api.jquery.com/one

Comment: thanks both of you. I use one('click', function (e) {$(this).attr('disabled', 'disabled');}) ? and what about applying the css class when clicked?

Comment: still not working,I edited my code

Comment: It seems that you have messed closing curly/round brackets in script block resulting in syntax error.

Comment: I edited the question by putting correct brackets ,i have my button rendered but when I click the button disappear so the disabled style is not applied